# sqlite outputing variable into js

Tags: javascript, sqlite, variables

So I have a database with SQLite and I'm happy but when I try to output a value into a local variable I receive this error:

```
console.log(UserMurderCoins);
ReferenceError: UserMurderCoins is not defined
```

My Code:

```
sql.get(`SELECT * FROM monney WHERE userId ="${message.author.id}"`)
   .then(row => {var UserMurderCoins = row.coins});

console.log(UserMurderCoins);
```

Comment: `sql.get` is an asynchronous function. `row => {var UserMurderCoins = row.coins}` is executed later than `console.log(UserMurderCoins);`. Also the scope of the variable is the function body.

Comment: Read more of asynchronous programming (e.g. first google link: https://dev.to/siwalik/async-programming-basics-every-js-developer-should-know-in-2018-a9c )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Lemix said in comment, `sql.get` is an async function and the `console.log` would be executed before it is done.

Also be aware of the **variable [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)**. `var UserMurderCoins` is defined inside a `then` function and is accessed out of the scope. So, it wouldn't be defined even if the statement was executed after the `sql.get.then`.

you can either run the `console.log` inside the `then` function or define the variable globally and only assign it inside the `then` function.

---

**UPDATE:**

To be more comfortable with promises, you can use `async await` syntax.

I modified your code with a little changes to be working.

```
async function f() {
var UserMurderCoins = (await sql.get(`SELECT * FROM monney WHERE userId ="${message.author.id}"`)).coins;

console.log(UserMurderCoins);
}

f();
```

Comment: So, how do I declare the variable globally ?
And will declaring it globally will allow me to put the console.log() outside of the .then function ?

Comment: you can write `var UserMurderCoins;` before `sql.get` but because your `sql.get` function is a promise you still will have problem. I will update the answer to contain a working code soon.